# Kubernetes API version

Tags: api, kubernetes, version, kubernetes-apiserver

I read official and non official documentation, googled it many times, but still don't understand.

How API Kubernetes version corresponds to Kubernetes version? So, we have Kubernetes 1.22 version and which API does it have? If we upgrade K8s version, will API version be upgraded as well or k8s upgrades API version regardless of server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each k8’s versions have different kubernetes [API versions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/_print/), [API Versioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-versioning).
If we update the k8’s versions then we need to update its new API versions too then only we don’t have any breakages in the service or else we can roll back to previous k8’s versions.

We have Kubernetes 1.22 version and which API does it have? In v1.22 some APIs got deprecated for detailed information of APIs.Refer this doc for [API changes in v1.22](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/).